# Specify an HTML element before the custom function through dot (like element.myFunction)?

Tags: javascript, function

So, I have my custom function that I want to do something with the specified element, like:

```
const element = document.querySelector('some-element')
element.myFunc()

function myFunc() {
//do something with element specified before the dot
}
```

But this gives me an error that this is not a function. The only thing I can do is to specify the element as an argument of my function, like that:

```
const element = querySelector('some-element')
myFunc(element)

function myFunc(element) {
   //do something with element
}
```

What do I need to be able to use my function through the dot, like `element.myFunction()` ?

Comment: What is the problem you try to solve with this? What's the problem with a parameter?

Comment: I just want to use it like element.myFunction(), but not myFunction(element).

Comment: Why? There's almost no reason why this would be a good idea (and why you would need to mess with the internals of `Element` or use a sledgehammer like `Proxy`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with just passing the element to the function.  But if you *really want to* do this...

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).  So you could add your function to the `Element` prototype.  For example:

```js
Element.prototype.myFunc = function () {
  console.log(this);
};

const element = document.querySelector('#some-element')
element.myFunc();
```

```html
<div id="some-element">test</div>
```

It's worth pointing out though that getting into this habit can potentially lead to issues.  As pointed out in a comment below, this "pollutes" every element in the DOM.  So it's best to be careful with this approach.

Comment: _"So you could add your function to the Element prototype"_ and pollute _every_ element in the DOM...

Comment: The reason is that I want to make a library that everyone can easily use this function to get some UI features on element they specify. Is that bad approach?

Comment: @Max: It's certainly an uncommon approach.  As an alternative, you might create a custom object for your library which encapsulates the functionality for getting and operating on elements.  Very much like how jQuery works, for example.  Instead of modifying the `Element`, you create your own object which in some way *wraps* an `Element` with additional functionality.  It's a form of favoring composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You asked to add a function as a property of an element. That's an example:

```
function myFunc(){
    console.log(this);
}

element.myFunc = myFunc;
element.myFunc();
```